# Getting read values from file and then appending them to textArea

Tags: java, oop, javafx, io, event-handling

I am currently working on an assignment in which I need to make an application that has two buttons: read/write, and a textArea with a gray background and blue text, that will display the read content of a file that is written to on button press. I have to save an array of 5 numbers, the date, and a double (2.5).
I have gotten to the point of getting everything to work except for the appending of the text to the textArea... no matter where I seem to pass the value it gives me an error or tells me that it doesn't exist as a variable!

My question is: How do I get the values that I have read from the file to update the text in the textArea instead of just console?

Here is my first file which will create the application and populate the scene. The buttons and text area are all the correct color.

```
package chapter17;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;


public class Exercise17_5 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button write = new Button("Write");
        Button read = new Button("Read");


        TextArea readText = new TextArea("This is text testing...");
        readText.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        readText.setPrefRowCount(5);
        readText.setWrapText(true);
        readText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue");
        //readText.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey");
        readText.setFont(Font.font("Times", 20));
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(write, read, readText);

        ReadWrite readWriting = new ReadWrite();

        write.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                readWriting.write();
            }
            catch (IOException excepiton) {
                excepiton.printStackTrace();
        }});
        read.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                readWriting.read();

            }
            catch (IOException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Scene scene  = new Scene(hBox,550,550);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise 17.5");
        primaryStage.show();

        Region region = (Region) readText.lookup(".content");
        region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray");

    }


}
```

Here is the second file that will contain the read and write methods, and the variables that store what is read. I can get them to print out to console as demonstrated below. They need to be appended to my already existing textArea readText.

```
package chapter17;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class ReadWrite extends Exercise17_5 {

    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    public ReadWrite(){

    };


    public void write() throws IOException {


        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Exercise17_5.dat"))){
            output.writeObject(numbers);
            output.writeObject(new Date());
            output.writeDouble(2.5);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        try{
            FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("Exercise17_5.dat");
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(inputFile);
            int[] numbers = (int[])(input.readObject());
            java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)(input.readObject());
            double decimal = (double)(input.readDouble());
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(decimal);
            System.out.println(date);
            input.close();



        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException exception2){
            exception2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to update the textArea with the values that I have read into the variables??

Comment: Have the `read` method return the data it read in. Then when you call it you can just append it to the text area.

Comment: @James_D Hmm.. that does make some sense to me as to how to get the values into the initial class, could you elaborate? My instructor is a little slacking on answering our help queries this semester :(

Comment: The data you are reading is a strange collection of values. Normally you would just have a single object in a serialized file like that (so you would have a class that encapsulated the `int[]`, `Date`, and `double` values). If you did that, your `read` method could return an instance of that class. Otherwise you could just format them into a `String` in the `read` method and then return that.

Comment: @James_D so I tried to convert them to a string and the method appears not to work on the array, when I convert the date to a string it does it; though when I attempt to append it it says 'date not resolved or cannot be a field.' It's been 2 days now and no help from my 'teacher' so I'm at my wits end.

Comment: "The method appears not to work on the array". What does that mean?

Comment: @JamesD when I tried to use toString() on my decimal variable it told me it could not be invoked on the primitive type double. I got it to work on the date variable but it still won't append to the textArea when I try to use append text on the instance of ReadWrite in Exercise17_5 file.